# Creating and writing data to a table is MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

EDIT: Changed as I have a different issue with the same code

2nd Edit: Adding additional code that seems to be casuing the issue

I have created a vba program in access that aggregates data from a number of external sources and write the results into a new table. Ideally when I run the program I want to wipe out all of the data that is currently in the table and replace it with my new data. I am currently currently deleting all of the data in the table... then writing my new data

Here is the code for reference

```
Function getTestFixtures(FixtureName As String) As Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = OpenDatabase(GetDBPath & "TestFixtures.xlsx", False, False, "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;")

If db Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Can't find the file!", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name
     Exit Function
End If

Set getTestFixtures = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [" & FixtureName & "$]")

End Function
```

The recordset created above is modified and the output data is placed in a dictionary and passed to this function.

```
Sub Write_OTDC_Data(POlist As Dictionary)
Dim Rst As Recordset


DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.runsql "Delete * from [OTDC Results]"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True


Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OTDC Results")

With Rst

  For Each key In POlist.Keys
    .AddNew
    For i = 0 To 9
        .Fields(i).value = POlist(key)(i)
    Next
    .Update
  Next
.Close
End With
End Sub
```

My Problem is that I get the following error if I try to change anything after running both of the above procuedures.

[image: Error Message]

Running either in isolation does not generate the error.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not wish to run a delete query rather than drop the table?

Comment: @Remou No.... I have had issues with data loss of the data to be uploaded from key violations. I'll give that a try since it is a simple fix

Comment: I do not think keys on a data upload table are such a good idea. It slows things down and can, as you have found, be a nuisance. Can you not leave the key out?

Comment: @ Remou.... thanks for the guidance. Deleting the records seems to be working out for now. the record sets are not large enough to warrant keys or indexes at this point.

Comment: I doubt that it is the code you have posted that is causing the problem.

Comment: @ Remou I would tend to agree with you, however i am using a test script to test all of the functions Ive built. I do not get the problem until I enable this function call. Other activities I am doing is connecting to an excel file to retrieve the test fixtures, and createing custom objects and manipulating them. These other activities do not lock the database. Should I be more explicit than using CurrentDB object?

Comment: CurrentDB is fine. Even though I could not see anything that would cause a problem, I was curious so I tested before I posted that comment, and I had no problems. Where are you getting the dictionary you are passing to this procedure? You might like to post that procedure as well. The only difference between this and numberless other procedures is that dictionary. You can also try copying everything and running just this and the procedure that passes the dictionary. I am pretty sure you will not have a problem unless it lies in the dictionary procedure.

Comment: @ Remou your comment led me to do some additional testing, and I only seem to get the error after connecting to an external db (test excel sheets that mimic my data warehouse). Is it possible that opening this connection is causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, especially if you are using ADO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure whether this question is still unresolved.  In case it's not, I have some suggestions for you to try, but not a lot of confidence they will cure the problem.

Try `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` to import the sheet's data into a scratch table instead of using OpenDatabase with the workbook.

In your `MsgBox`, I wonder whether `ThisWorkbook.Name` means anything to an Access application.  Aside from that, I would check whether the workbook exists, then open it (or import the sheet from it) only if the file is found.

```
If Len(Dir(GetDBPath & "TestFixtures.xlsx")) = 0 Then
    'not found
Else
    'use it
End If
```

Actually I'm unclear why you don't get an error from `OpenDatabase` if the workbook file doesn't exist.  And that makes me suspicious of `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`  Never, ever turn SetWarnings off.  Doing so suppresses important information.  And it is completely unnecessary. Set a DAO.Database object variable to `CurrentDB()`, then use this instead:

```
dbObjectVariable.Execute "Delete from [OTDC Results]", dbFailOnError
```

Add an error handler to deal with any problems dbFailOnError exposes.

Finally, this bears repeating because it's so important.  **NEVER** turn SetWarnings off.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my code. I'll clarify what the error is exactly. The code above runs fine (and i haven't turned off warnings). somehow after the above runs, it locks the DB into a unusable state. I agree with you about the msgbox statment, it probably won't run properly in the event of a missing file